# debug seg fault in boost::math::lanczos with libpcl_surface

Tags: c++, debugging, boost, segmentation-fault, point-cloud-library

I get the following error only when I debug using gdb on my code compiled with debug flag

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffc79a7ff0 in boost::math::lanczos::lanczos_initializer<boost::math::lanczos::lanczos17m64, long double>::init::init() ()
from /usr/lib/libpcl_surface.so.1.7
```

OS: unbutu 14.04

I have the latest pcl library (1.7 Sprikelhof) and boost library (1.54)

Note, there is no segfault when running outside gdb.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the GTSAM library. I get the segfault every time, regardless of whether I run in GDB.  Please post an answer if you find one.

Comment: ran into the same issue, somehow it works if I disable C++11.

Comment: Same problem here with Spherical Bessel Functions of the First and Second Kinds (sph_bessel) from boost 1.58.0: segmentation fault if C++11 enabled.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue when compiling using `-std=c++11` but only in `Debug` mode: `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)`.
In `Release` or `RelWithDebInfo` mode, instead, everything was working as expected.

I solved the issue optimizing the compiled code (in `Debug` mode) with the `-O1` option. i.e. `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -O1")`.

I don't why it works but it's working for me.